# My node js code does return 200 but my AFNetworking still failed

Tags: objective-c, node.js, express

```
app.post("/points/update_descriptions", function(request, response){
    console.log("update descriptions!!!!");
    var req_body = request.body;
    console.log(req_body.point_id);
    cradle.get(req_body.point_id, function(err, doc){
        if(err)
            response.status(500);
        else{
            console.log("descriptions: "+doc);
            cradle.merge(req_body.point_id, {
                descriptions: req_body.descriptions
            }, function(merge_err, merge_res){
                if(merge_err) {
                    console.log("error!"+merge_err);
                    response.status(500).json("failed");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("200!!!");
                    response.status(200).json("success");
                }
            });
            response.status(200);
        }
    });
});




[[Marker getAFManager] POST:[SERVICE_URL stringByAppendingString:@"points/update_descriptions/"] parameters:@{@"point_id": selected_point_in_point_details, @"descriptions": self.descriptions.text} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self showAlert:@"success" withMessage:@"success"];
        NSLog(@"satus: %d", operation.response.statusCode);
        self.submit_btn.titleLabel.text = @"Submit";
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        //[self showAlert:@"failed" withMessage:@"failed"];
        NSLog(@"satus error: %d", operation.response.statusCode);
    }];
```

so the node js "console.log("200!!!");
                        response.status(200).json("success");" always executed and return 200, but my objective-c code's failed block always executed , any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you need to drop `response.status(200);` from the last line of your `if/else` block

Comment: It still not working without that response.status(200); ,  I added that line just because it was always 500.

Comment: Could you add `console.log(err)` and show error message?

Comment: good point! however it never had err messages, it always go to console.log("200!!!");
                    response.status(200).json("success");.....weird